# HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA returns HAL_ERROR

Tags: i2c, c, dma

These are my I2C init functions in the stm32f4_hal_msp.c file:

```
void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c) {
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if (hi2c->Instance == I2C1) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_MspInit 0 */
    
    /* USER CODE END I2C1_MspInit 0 */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**I2C1 GPIO Configuration
    PB6     ------> I2C1_SCL
    PB7     ------> I2C1_SDA
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_MspInit 1 */
    hdma_i2c_rx.Instance = DMA1_Stream0;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_1;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_i2c_rx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_i2c_rx) != HAL_OK) {
      Error_Handler();
    }
    __HAL_LINKDMA(hi2c,hdmarx,hdma_i2c_rx);
        
    /* USART1_TX Init */
    hdma_i2c_tx.Instance = DMA1_Stream7;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_1;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_i2c_tx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_i2c_tx) != HAL_OK) {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(hi2c,hdmatx,hdma_i2c_tx);
  }
```

And this is the I2C init function in main.c:

```
/*
* @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
*/

static void MX_I2C1_Init(void) {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;

  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Analogue filter */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Digital filter */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */
}
```

When I call the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA` function I get HAL_ERROR. Why this happening? When I use the `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit` instead of `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA` there is no error. How can I solve this problem?

I just one time call the `setValue` function like this:

```
uint8_t dataToStore[7] = {0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD,0x00,0x11,0x22};
setValue(&hi2c1, 0xA0, pageAdress, dataToStore);
```

This is the setValue:

```
void setValue(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t deviceAddress, uint16_t pageAdress, uint8_t* registerValue) {
  uint16_t bufferLength = 2;
  uint8_t dummyVariableArray[2 + bufferLength];
  uint64_t msTickTimer ;
  msTickTimer = desmo.TimeStamp + (uint64_t)EEPROM_TRANSCEIVE_TIMEOUT;
    
 dataArray[0] = (uint8_t)(pageAdress >> 8);
 dataArray[1] = (uint8_t)pageAdress;
    
 uint8_t  j;
 for (j = 0; j < 2U + bufferLength; j++) {
   dataArray[j + 2U] = registerValue[j];
 }
    
 while (HAL_I2C_GetState(hi2c) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY) {
 }
    
  if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(hi2c, (uint16_t)deviceAddress, (uint8_t*)dataArray, (2 + bufferLength))!= HAL_OK) {
  }

  // after this function I stuck in the I2c Event interrupt
}
```

**EDIT**

When I add the `I2C1_EV_IRQHandler` interupt this function returns HAL_OK but I stuck in the loop in `I2C1_EV_IRQHandler` function. How can I solve this problem?

```
void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler(void) {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_EV_IRQn 0 */
  //**** I am stuck in here !!!    
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_EV_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(&hi2c1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_EV_IRQn 1 */
        
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_EV_IRQn 1 */
}
        
/**
* @brief This function handles I2C1 event interrupt.
*/
void I2C1_ER_IRQHandler(void) {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_EV_IRQn 0 */
  // SerialPrint("\n!!");
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_EV_IRQn 0 */
          
  HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(&hi2c1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_EV_IRQn 1 */
        
  /* USER CODE END I2C1_EV_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged at which point it returns the error? Have you debugged which error causes the error IRQ hander? Why don't you let the HAL handle the IRQs since you are using the HAL?

Comment: HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA after the this function I checked only two times HAL_I2C_GetState and it return  HAL_I2C_STATE_BUSY_TX after that I stuck in the I2C1_EV_IRQHandler and I didnt quit this interrupt

Comment: I also added interrupt details

Comment: Then show the full code. If you run that code in a loop it will start the DMA transfer and it will then try to start another when first is already running so of course that is an error how you try to use the DMA transfer.

Comment: I added all details now, I call setValue function just one time and program stuck in the interrupt

Answer (score 0):

The while loop tries to start DMA transfers until starting a DMA tranfer fails. So your code does what you ask. Don't try to start multiple DMA transfers. Start only one and wait for it to finish before starting another one.

Comment: if I change with "while" to "if" I get same result When I check the     if(__HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(&hi2c1, I2C_FLAG_BUSY) == SET)
in interrupt Busy flag always SET

Comment: I suggest trying without DMA first. Use the blocking calls if you can't get the DMA working.

Comment: I've already try if I using blocking mode it works as I said in my topic. I have a problem with DMA

Comment: What is your suggestion I couldnt find any solution

Comment: The next problem is that in the I2C_ER_IRQHandler, you are calling HAL_EV_IRQ. I don't understand why are writing those yourself, why you can't let the CubeIDE or CubeMX generate a working codebase for you?

Comment: I've already added with CubeMx, I didnt add myself. I added ER and EV interrupts together with CubeMx